# Convert Date to CYYMMDD SQL-Server

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2012, format

I am interested in converting a date value to `CYYMMDD` using native SQL Server 2012 functions.

I checked here:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

and couldn't find anything.

Anyone know?

C stands for century I guess...

Comment: I guess I could just hardcode the Century value and add the formatted date, but what value is for this century?

Comment: CONCAT(1, FORMAT(i.StartDate, 'yyMMdd')) works but is there someway to pick up the Century Identifier straight from SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the new `FORMAT` function in SQL Server 2012?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

You should be able to use something like this:

```
SELECT FORMAT(YourDateColumn, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

or whatever you really want to use - basically, [the same formatting options as in C# / .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are available when using `FORMAT`

Comment: I guess for now I can just hard-code it in using the FORMAT function you suggested. I'll select tomorrow morning if nobody else knows. Thanks.

Comment: Should be `yyyyMMdd`.  Case matters here.

Comment: @MattJohnson: correct - I was under the false impression that in T-SQL this didn't matter - but you're right, it does - fixed my post