# Get the date from a column as dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: sql, mysqli

If I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Director
(
   `DirectorNr` INTEGER NOT NULL,
   `First Name` VARCHAR (20),
   `Last Name` VARCHAR (30),
   `Age` INTEGER,
   `Movies` INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY(DirectorNr)
 );

CREATE TABLE Movies
(
   `MovieNr` INTEGER NOT NULL,
   `Title` VARCHAR (100),
   `Genre` VARCHAR (30),
   `USK` INTEGER,
   `Director` INTEGER NOT NULL,
   `Length` INTEGER,
   `Release` DATE,
   PRIMARY KEY (MovieNr),
   FOREIGN KEY (Director)
           REFERENCES Director (DirectorNr)
);

INSERT INTO Director 
VALUES (1, 'Peter', 'Jackson', 52, 17);

INSERT INTO Movies 
VALUES (1, 'The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey', 'Fantasy', 12, 1, 169, '2012/12/12');
```

how can i get the the date (Release) in this format: `dd.mm.yyyy` with a SELECT query?

I've tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24292832 but it does not work for me.

And is it also possible to INSERT the date as `dd.mm.yyyy`?

Comment: Consider formatting the date with when you *display* it (for example with PHP, if you use that).

Comment: Tuksn: 2012/12/12 ... what is month and what is day ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
select date_format(Release, '%d.%m.%Y')
from movies
```

And the date is always **stored** the same way. You can change the representation in your select queries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
INSERT INTO Movies 
 VALUES (1, 'The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey', 'Fantasy', 12, 1, 169,
  STR_TO_DATE('2012/12/12', '%Y/%m/%d'));
```

and for SELECT:

```
SELECT FORMAT(`Release`, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM Movies
```

Comment: Sql date format?  Your code deserves an upvote but that opening paragraph doesn't.

Comment: +1 for the INSERT worked great, but with FORMAT i get always useless values with LibreOffice Base. date_format worked great.

Comment: What you mean "useless values"?

Comment: `20,121,212,`for my example.

Comment: Show your sql query ;)

Comment: SELECT FORMAT(`Release`, '%d.%m.%Y') FROM Movies